# Is there anything equivalent to middleware in Openresty or Lua web apps?

Tags: openresty

I'm learning Openresty for a small web app. Is there an abstraction layer   Lua web apps and frameworks?  For example: Python/WSGI, Ruby/Rack, Elixir/Plug.

The most recent one I found for Lua seems out-of-date: [APItools/lua-resty-rack](https://github.com/APItools/lua-resty-rack)

There is also [WSAPI](http://keplerproject.github.io/wsapi/) and [WSAPI-Openresty](https://github.com/ignacio/wsapi-openresty), but I couldn't find any maintained middleware/projects that utilize it.

Do Openresty apps simply not use this type of abstraction layer for most production apps? Or is it not needed because of the Openresty architecture?

Comment: OpenResty has offered api to access headers, request_path and other http relative information. Could you tell me the reason to add a middleware above it?

Comment: I think what you are saying is: "it does not need it middleware because it already has a well-designed api". Which I agree with. So that answers my question. Thanks very much.